# sqlAlchemy Select with like and max

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I' trying to select the highest value from column *'id'* in table *'tablename'* which is beginning with 'v3' and Ends with 't'.

This works finde with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT max(_id_) 
FROM _db.tablename_ 
WHERE _id_ LIKE 'v3%'
AND _id_ NOT LIKE '%T'
```

But it seems that I have some bugs in my sqlAlchemy snippet and couldn't find the mistake.

```
query = session.query(_CLASSNAME_._ID_).filter(
        func.max(_CLASSNAME_._ID_.like('v4%'), not_(_CLASSNAME_._ID_.like('%T'))))

for _res in query.all():
    print(_res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to calculate the *max* of a column you need to query like this:

```
session.query(func.max(Table.column))
```

To use Boolean operations in filtering, you need to import equivalent functions from sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy import not_
```

Your query could be something like this:

```
query = (session.query(func.max(_CLASSNAME_._ID_))
         .filter(and_(_CLASSNAME_._ID_.like('v4%'),
                      not_(_CLASSNAME_._ID_.like('%T'))))
```